# Combining 2 string characters

Tags: java, string

I need to create a method which asks the user to enter two words. The first word in one variable, and second word in another variable. The program is to combine the user’s entry as shown in below:
Enter first word: Tree
Enter second word: Computer
String Manipulator: TreCom
** ensure the output is in all capitals, displayed from a single variable

Here's what I have so far (which isn't much):

```
public static void  StringManipulator ()
{
String v1,v2;
c.println("What is the first word?");
v1 = c.readLine();
c.println("What is the second word?");
v2 = c.readLine();
```

how would you combine the 2 strings so that only the first 3 letters show?

Thanks

Comment: The first three letters of each word or the first three letters of the concatenated word?  BTW what is c's type?

Comment: @wickeddreams by the way welcome to stackoverflow if you find any of the answers usefull please mark them as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the substring of each string, and then concatenate them, e.g.

```
// Extract substrings
String ss1 = v1.substring(0, 3);
String ss2 = v2.substring(0, 3);

// Concatenate substrings
String result = ss1 + ss2;

// Output in all uppercase
System.out.println(result.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get this right you want to get an input of two words and then get the first three letters and print them out?

in that case try the following:

```
String word1 = v1.substring(0,3);
String word2 = v2.substring(0,3);
```

now if you want to print these two you simply just do:

```
System.out.println(word1 + " "+word2);
```

you can exclude the space between to get the letters in 1 word.

Answer (score 0):

This method will combine the first 3 letters of two strings:

```
String combineWords(String firstWord, String secondWord){
firstWord = firstWord.substring(0,2);
secondWord = secondWord.substring(0,2);
String combinedWords  = firstWord + secondWord;
return "First word: " + firstWord + ", second word: "+ secondWord + "; Both combined are: " + combinedWords;
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
String v1,v2;
c.println("What is the first word?");
v1 = c.readLine();
c.println("What is the second word?");
v2 = c.readLine();
System.out.println(combineWords(v1, v2));
```